# Is there any API to download 45 degree aerial imagery (bird's eye) from Bing?

Tags: bing-maps

There's an API for downloading static maps, aerial imagery, etc.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701724.aspx

But I cannot find a way to download bird's eye view imagery. Is it possible at all?

Comment: i am facing similar kind of problem. Can you share how did you solve it. I have seen the answer but it doesn't work now.

Comment: Solved it. https://gist.github.com/salman-ghauri/87a1544d2097615d00870b7164bfd7de

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have to use the ImageryMetaData service for birdseye and stitch the tiles together yourself:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701716.aspx